# How to identify and remove a point in a data set relating to the QQ plot

Tags: r, plot

I have ran a regression model and I am checking the residual diagnostics and I have identified one point that i want to try an remove. Once i remove this i will re-run the model and see what changes have been made. The plot below is what my output is.

[image]

My understanding is that the bottom right point is the 12th point in my data set. I checked the Cooks Distance and the Leverage of this point and have decided to try and remove it but i am having an issue in R doing so. AM i able to just do the following:

```
newdata<-olddata[-12,]
```

When i try to do this and run the analysis again the QQ plot still has 12 in the same place. So my question would be is this the right way to remove a data point and is there anyway to remove several data points at once?

Comment: `newdata <- olddata[-c(12,13,20),]`

Comment: To elaborate on the comment of @shuckle,  once you remove point 12, point 13 becomes the new point 12.  Since that is also an outlier, it will show up in your revised graph.